# How to navigate iframe using form (HTML)

Tags: html, forms, iframe, navigation, submit

OK I have an iFrame embedded on a website named "iframe"
And a single line text form called "form"
And a submit button called "navigate"

I want the "iframe" to navigate to the url typed in the "form" when i press "navigate"

Also:
Is it possible to **add** the url of the iframe to the end of the webpage url **eg below**
http://www.example.com.htm/http://www.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the iframe URL by having your "Navigate" Button call a onClick javascript function or do an action on submit i.e.

```
<form action="JavaScript:navigate()">...</form>
```

as for the function itself you can set an ID to the iframe which can be used by the javascript to change the URL location.

```
<script> function navigate(){ window.frames['Iframe'].document.location.href = document.getElementByID('newLink').value; } </script>
```

and for the iframe do:

```
<iframe id="Iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

So your final code should be something like this.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>iFrame</title>
    <script>
    function navigate(){
window.frames['Iframe'].document.location.href =  document.getElementByID('newLink').value;
}    
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="JavaScript:navigate()">URL: <input type="text" id="newLink">
```

```
     <iframe id="Iframe" src=""></iframe> 


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me what each element (button, form, frame) individual scripts would be?? THX

Comment: I have tried using the code, but the iframe does not navigate to the url in the form. :O thx